# Gradient of Least Squares function

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, maximum-likelihood

[image]

I have trouble understand the gradient of equation 3.12 with respect to $W$.

Tn is a scalar output variable, $\phi(x)$ and $W$ are  $N \times 1$ dimensional.

According to the book, the gradient results in a $1 \times N$ dimensional vector, since $\phi(x)$ transpose is $1 \times N$ dimensional. The gradient is supposed to result in a vector with same dimension as $W$. But this is not the case. Can someone explain?

Comment: The gradient leaves in the dual space to $\mathbb R^{N \times 1}$, i.e $\mathbb R^{1 \times N}$. Each $t_n - w^T\phi(x_n)$ is a scalar whilst $\phi(x_n)^T$ is a $1 \times N$ vector. Thus each $(t_n - w^T\phi(x_n))\phi(x_n)^T$ is a $1 \times N$ vector. So the gradient as computed (3.13) is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this situation is analogous to the derivative versus directional derivative (as might be familiar from multi-variable calculus).

Recall, given a function say $f:R^n \to R$, the *gradient* is defined as $\nabla f = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i$ or alternatively $\left(f_{x_1}, f_{x_2}, \dots, f_{x_n}\right)$ while the *directional derivative* is given as $D_\vec{u}\, f = \nabla f (\vec{u})$ which amounts to the inner product $\nabla f \cdot \vec{u}$ and can also be expressed as $\vec{u}^T\nabla f$.

In your case, considering the function $E_D$ you have as being evaluated in the $\vec{w}$ direction may very well be the reason you wind up with scalars. You'll notice that this error function does, in-fact, vary with different values of $\vec{w}$ as expected.

Comment: well..the line before 3.13 says the gradient wrt w is evaluated.I don't understand what you are trying to convey..the gradient is a vector quantity whereas a directional derivative is a scalar right.My question was that the gradient evaluated is actually of  1 X N rather than the transpose of it..

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to convey.

Comment: But the line clearly says gradient is evaluated..why is this resulting in an 1 X N dimensional vector?

Comment: Are you now asking about why equation 3.13 has any meaning?

Comment: My question is that, since 3.13 represents a gradient, it should be a vector quantity..ie of dimension N X 1 (Same as W) . Why is it of dimension 1 x n?

Comment: Please notice that $(f_{x_1}, \cdots, f_{x_n})$ is the gradient of a function (which is standard and $1\times n$). Equation 3.13 appears to be the gradient of equation 3.12 with respect to $\vec{x}$ - observe the 2's cancelling and the power being lowered followed by the derivative of the vector which is a little bit strange appearing as a transpose, but this is likely for the same reasons as the usual gradient appears as a row vector which comes from more in depth study of tensor analysis.

Comment: ohh..so the gradient is taken as a row vector for notational convenience?

Comment: At level of multi variable calculus it is notational convenience, but it actually serves a purpose and means something in the language of differential geometry and proper tensor analysis.

Comment: Till now i have always encountered the gradient to be a column vector..so it is taken interchangbly?

Comment: We write $\nabla f = (f_x, f_y, f_z)$ so that $\nabla f (\vec{d})$ is already in the proper form of an inner product. That is, 

$$\nabla f (\vec{d}) = \left[f_x, f_y, f_z\right]\left[\begin{matrix}d_x\\d_y\\d_z\end{matrix}\right] = \langle \nabla f, \vec{d}\rangle$$